# Conformality of stereographic projection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have to solve the following exercise:

*Let $S^m(r)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}|\sum_i (x^i)^2=r^2, r>0\}$ and let $\Phi$ be the Stereographic projection $$\Phi: S^m(r)\setminus\{(0,...,0,r)\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$$
Show, $\Phi$ is a conformal mapping, i.e. for $(S^m,\tilde{g})$ and $(\mathbb{R}^m,g)$ there exists $f\in C^2(S^m(r))$ with $f>0 $ such that $$f^2\tilde{g}=\Phi^*g$$ where $\tilde{g}$ is the induced metric $S^m\subset \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ and $g$ the Euclidean metric.*

Now, I already have made the connection between the metrics in this way:
\begin{align*}
\tilde{g}=g^{sphere}_{\alpha\beta}=&\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\beta}}X^jg_{ij}\\
=& \frac{1}{\partial x^\alpha \partial x^{\beta}}(\sum_i \partial^2 X^i)^2
\end{align*}

If I'm comparing now $\tilde{g}$ and $g$ there is of course the difference  of $\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\beta}}X^j$ between them, for which I can reason, the properties mentioned for $f$, **but is that enough**?

**Don't I need to look at some explicit expression of $\Phi$ to compare them?**
Otherwise any map between a sphere with induced metric and Euclidean space would be conformal, which is not the case, right?

Comment: You need a *scalar* relationship $f^2 \tilde g_{ij} = g_{ij}$ for conformality. There is a big difference between this and $\tilde g_{\alpha \beta} = X^i_\alpha X^j_\beta g_{ij}$.

Comment: What do you mean by scalar relationship? $f$ needs to be a function which is twice differentiable. wouldn't that fit the factor $(X^i_{\alpha} X^i_{\beta})^{-1}$?

Comment: Pay attention to the indices! These are two very different operations - it's comparable to the difference between $u = c v$ and $u = M(v)$ where $u,v$ are vectors, $c$ is a scalar and $M$ is a matrix.

Comment: Your expression $\frac{1}{\partial x^\alpha \partial x^{\beta}}(\sum_i \partial^2 X^i)^2$ is also nonsense.

Comment: Could you please edit it for the better? I'm still having trouble with this.

Comment: "No", that is not enough. "Yes", you need to use the special form of stereographic projection somewhere. :) Do you have (or know how to find) a representation of stereographic projection? Once you have this expression, do you know how to compute the induced metric?